# Download file via PHP with Unity WebGL

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

I'm using PHP with Unity WebGL and can successfully create an image and save it on a server. I would now like to download that image through the browser that my Unity program is running in via PHP. No download appears when the PHP script is visited through Unity, but it works just fine if I type in the URL manually.

Here is the PHP script I am using:

```
$file_url = __DIR__ . "/IMAGES/OUTPUT_IMAGES/TEST_.png";
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\""); 
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file_url); 
exit();
```

Here is the C# code in Unity that calls this script:

```
uwr = UnityWebRequest.Get(DownloadImageURL);
yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

if (uwr.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError)
{
     print("Error downloading file: " + uwr.error);
}
```

[Here's a screenshot of the browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqzbP.png)

Comment: And what do your weblogs show

Comment: I added a screenshot of what the console outputs. No errors. I'm assuming that is coming from the reafile() in PHP?

Comment: `No download appears when the PHP script is visited through Unity` .. do you get any errors instead? What did they say?

Comment: No errors @derHugo maybe UnityWebRequest.Get isn't the right way to interact with downloads via PHP? I just want to force a download through WebGL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work-around that was a little different than what I wanted. I ended up using `Application.OpenURL()` in Unity where the URL was a php script that downloaded the file. Basically I wasn't able to download anything with readfile from using `UnityWebRequest.Get` but it worked with `Application.OpenURL`.

Comment: Do you mean that there was no data in the response?
Unity's web request doesn't leverage the browser APIs the way it would from a regular anchor. Instead, the request will come back with the binary data, which you'd then need to do something with (e.g., open a save file dialog and write to the file specified).